Write file extensions and their occurrences in a list into a dictionary?
How can I solve this with loops, without regular expressions?
Write a function that accepts a list of file names and returns a dictionary with extensions as keys and their occurrences as value.
Example:
#print(count_file_types(["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "preso.pptx"]))
#=> {"jpg": 2, "pptx": 1}

I tried this, but I guess it’s all wrong:
def count_file_types(string_arr): 
    
    arr = []
    for i in string_arr:
        arr.append(i.split("."))
    return(arr)
    print(arr)

    freq = {}
    for i in arr: 
        if i in freq: 
            freq[i] += 1
        else: 
            freq[item] = 1
    return freq
    print(freq)
  
  
print(count_file_types(['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'preso.pptx']))   


How is it all wrong?

You could (not should) do this without any imported modules as follows:
def count_file_types(filenames: list[str]) -> dict[str, int]:
    result = {}
    for filename in filenames:
        suffix = filename.split(".")[-1]
        result[suffix] = result.get(suffix, 0) + 1
    return result

print(count_file_types(["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "preso.pptx"]))

Output:
{'jpg': 2, 'pptx': 1}

Note:
For the sample data given in the question, this is significantly faster than the (arguably) more Pythonic approach proposed by @James

Thank you! I can't quite wrap my head around this part of code:  result[suffix] = result.get(suffix, 0) + 1, could you explain this bit by bit please?

@Evanto See this documentation

You can use pathlib.Path and collections.Counter to do this.
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

def count_ext(file_list: list[str]):
    return dict(Counter(Path(f).suffix.lstrip('.') for f in file_list))


perhaps another, more compact approach
def count_file_ext(file_list):
    ext_list = [ext.split('.')[-1] for ext in file_list]
    return {ext:ext_list.count(ext) for ext in set(ext_list)}


Works for the data shown in the question but would not produce correct results if the list contained the following (valid) filename: abc.xyz.txt

made edits, thanks for pointing it out

Edited my initial solution, this works, apparently:
def count_file_types(string_arr): 

arr = []
for i in string_arr:
    arr.append(i.split("."))
    print(arr) 
    
freq = {}

for (name, ext) in arr:
    if ext in freq: 
        freq[ext] += 1
    else: 
        freq[ext] = 1
return freq
print(freq)


This will work for the values shown in the original question but is not a generic solution. Consider that a.b.txt is a valid filename
